# In-place editable field in web grid

Tags: smalltalk, aida

I'm trying to add an in-place editable field to a web grid like this:

```
WebGrid new
  columnNames: #('Test');
  columnAspects: #(nil);
  column: 1 addBlock: [:o | WebInPlaceEditableText aspect: #test for: o];
  collection: self objects.
```

However, when pointing my browser to the page containing this element, I get:

> Too late to add page headers, page is already streaming to response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code at the beginning of the method where your code resides:

```
ScriptaculousLibrary ensure
```

This library initialization call is otherwise done automatically by WebInPlaceEditableText but because in your case it resides in a block which is executed late in page streaming phase, when a page is already composed, this error occurs. Therefore the manual library initialization is needed.

Comment: I'm using VisualWorks, so I added: self style ensureScriptaculous.

Comment: But if you load latest 6.5 interim from Public Repository, you'll use a code above.